# Installation of bllim/laravel-to-jquery-validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Running into problems getting this package installed with composer...

bllim/laravel-to-jquery-validation

In composer.json I have

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.7",
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
```

Composer update returns..

[image]

Comment: What php version are you using? use the command `php -v` to see.

Comment: If you are using a version less than 5.4 you need to upgrade to use the package. And you cannot upgrade php within your composer.json.

Comment: I'm using php 5.3.13 and can't go above I'm afraid.

Comment: Without php 5.4 you are 'screwed' as they put it. As `illuminate/support` version 4.2 which is required by the package you want needs php 5.4 and will not install without it.

Comment: :-( Oh well.  Looks like I'll have to do my own client side validation. Thanks for the advise.  I thought that may be the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to bllim/laravel-to-jquery-validation is the package [Laravel 5 Javascript Validation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation). This package enables transparent Javascript Valditaion in your views based on [JQuery Validation Plugin](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) without need to write any javascript code

This is a basic example of how to reuse your validation rules in the controller .

**PostController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PostController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Define your validation rules in a property in 
     * the controller to reuse the rules.
     */
    protected $validationRules=[
                'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
                'body' => 'required',
    ];

    /**
     * Show the edit form for blog post
     * We create a JsValidator instance based on shared validation rules
     * @param  string  $post_id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($post_id)
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules);
        $post = Post::find($post_id);

        return view('edit_post')->with([
            'validator' => $validator,
            'post' => $post
        ])    

    }


    /**
     * Store the incoming blog post.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $v = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->validationRules]);

        if ($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }

        // do store stuff
    }
}
```

In the view you simply should print the *validator* object passed to the view. **Remember** that this package depends of JQuery and
you have to include before that *jsvalidation.js*

**edit_post.balde.php**

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="" id="ddd">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Title</label>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Array</label>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <textarea name="body"></textarea>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Scripts -->
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Laravel Javascript Validation -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
 {!! $validator !!}
```